# Facebook Auth: View users that logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I am doing a very basic Facebook auth for my site where users must log in with their facebook account. Of course I am storing everything in the db, but I am just curious if I can view that from the Facebook console / query that in some way? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: did u try this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ in developers.facebook.com, you should create a new app for your site, add ur site url as the web site url in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because there's no endpoint to request the list of your app users. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/

Comment: Strange. Any idea why facebook is not allowing this? Seems like a common thing you would want to be able to do.